# Can I Include php in functions.php? - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I need to call custom php script when I publish new post in WP. This function works, but include not. It is not included. Can it be working or is there any other way to include php file in functios.php?

```
function new_post_caller( $ID, $post )  {

    include( get_template_directory() . 'call_new_post.php?ID='.$ID.'' );

}

add_action( 'publish_mypost', 'new_post_caller', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass `get` parameters when using `include`

Comment: have you confirmed that `get_template_directory()` works?

Comment: Thank you, my problem is that GET value here. Do you have an idea how to call php script and insert any data there? Or must I include my code here without include() function (manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include script and pass a parameter to him, you can create function in including script and use construction like this:

some script to include (file.php):

```
function some_function ($id) {
 //some code, using $id
}
```

and calling file.php and pass a parameter:

```
include('file.php'); 
some_function(23);
```

Function include() simply adds the code from including file to the file where the function was originated
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I already resolved my problem by this way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `include( get_template_directory() . '/filetoinclude.php' );`
It will work.

Comment: Thank you, that was also my problem.

Answer (score 1):

function include() can includes only php/html files for execute, without GET or POST parametrs.

Comment: Thank you, that is my problem. Do you have an idea how to call php script and insert any data there? Or must I include my code here without include() function (manually)?

Comment: You can include your code without using get parametr. You want to include php script or u want to include text from WP post?